# VisualStudio2019のSDKにて 参照されているアセンブリより新しいバージョンを含む でエラー

Tags: c#, visual-studio

VisualStudio2019のSDKを用いた開発をしたいと思い、サンプルコード
https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples
の ErrorList などを使ってみたのですが下記のエラーが発生して困っています

```
エラー CS1705  アセンブリ 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI' (ID 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') は、参照されているアセンブリ 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic' (ID 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Logic, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') より新しいバージョンを含む
```

エラーコードからGoogleで調べましたが、ソリューションのNuGetパッケージの管理 でパッケージを更新すればいい(?)とあったので更新してもエラーが解除出来ませんでした。

最新のVisualStudio2019では古いプロジェクトのSDKは開発出来ないのでしょうか？
エラーを解除をするにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？
また、有識者の皆様はどのようにしてVisualStudioSDKの開発の知識、テクニック等を手に入れているのでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれません。[How adapt extension to Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55082659/9014308), [Visual Studio extensions and version ranges demystified](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-extensions-and-version-ranges-demystified/), [Visual Studio - Visual Studio の複数バージョン向け拡張機能の作成](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/visual-studio-creating-extensions-for-multiple-visual-studio-versions), [How to upgrade extensions...2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/)

Answer (score 1):

kunif 様
返答が遅れて申し訳ございません。
情報ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きました。

状況ですが、とりあえずはエラーは解除出来ました。
ミスっていたのは、対象のフレームワークが古かったため更新出来ておらず4.7.2にして ソリューションのNuGetパッケージの管理 をしたところ更新されエラーはなんとか通りました。

しかし、動作させてもgithubのReadme.mdにある通りに動作していないので、正しい作業だったのか検証+デバッグ中ですが、情報ありがとうございました。